# jQuery get element by custom property

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to manipulate a website with jQuery.

I can easily find an element by its classname:

```
<div class="SR">whatever</div>
$('.SR').hide();
```

Works just fine.

But now I have an element without a class I can use:

```
<div data-iid="sii2:112">whatever</div>
```

How can I access the element by the value of "data-iid" instead of a classname?

Comment: Update: Wow. I've been a while on SO. But never got so many (right) answers in a so small time. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the item without class using following method  **`$('[attribute="value"]')`**

```
$('div[data-iid="sii2:112"]').hide()
```

For more about attribute selector visit [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/syBLF/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
 $('div[data-iid="sii2:112"]').hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the attribute selector?

From http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

```
$( "a[data-iid]").hide();
```

or

```
$( "a[data-iid ='sii2:112']" ).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest way :

```
$("[data-iid='sii2:112']")
```

if you need to find all elements with that property you can do so using

```
$("*[data-iid]")
```